# C# Ninject binding from Dictionary<Type, Type>

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject

I'm using Ninject lib in my project. I have a task: I need to bind interfaces to services by passed `Dictionary<Type, Type>`, I prefer to use reflection.

Without reflection this is done so:

```
kernel.Bind<IUser>().To<User>();
```

Where IUser - interface, User - IUser implementation.

In reflection I'm doing so:

```
MethodInfo method = kernel.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "Bind");
MethodInfo genericBind = method.MakeGenericMethod(bind.Key);
MethodInfo bindResult = genericBind.Invoke(kernel,null).GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "To" && x.IsGenericMethod == true);
MethodInfo genericTo = bindResult.MakeGenericMethod(bind.Value);
genericTo.Invoke(kernel, null); //Error is here
```

but I get an error `System.Reflection.TargetException`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Which of the 4 lines prompts the error?

Comment: The last one. But i'm exactly shure, that bind.Value implemented from bind.Key...

Comment: You should invoke on bindResult I think.

Comment: Also you don't need to do any of this IKernel supports non generic implementation of the method  `kernel.Bind(typeof(IUser)).To(typeof(User))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your issue is that you are invoking the method on the kernel object and not on the result of the method. This will fix your problem

```
MethodInfo method = kernel.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "Bind");
MethodInfo genericBind = method.MakeGenericMethod(bind.Key);
var result = genericBind.Invoke(kernel,null);
MethodInfo bindResult = result.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "To" && x.IsGenericMethod == true);
MethodInfo genericTo = bindResult.MakeGenericMethod(bind.Value);
genericTo.Invoke(result, null); //Error is here
```

BUT all of this is unnecessary since the Bind function has a non generic implementation `kernel.Bind(typeof(IUser)).To(typeof(User))` so you can just do
`kernel.Bind(bind.Key).To(bind.Value)`